# update sql for part of the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table value like blow

```
id     value
 1    Default - Jimmy
 2    Market Return - Jimmy
 3    Sales Return - Jimmy
 11    Default - dfd
 21    Market Return - dfd
 31    Sales Return - dfd
```

now i  need to update Jimmy to Kanan in all 1,2,3 id  .
and dfd with Jimmy

How can i do it?

Comment: added please check

Comment: You need to normalize your data, don't store two pieces of info in the same column

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal update with `Replace` as follows:

```
update your_table
set value = replace(replace(value,'jimmy','kanan'),'dfd','jimmy')
```

Comment: there are so many record like this , can i do onetime without write again and again

Comment: Yeap, You can. But make sure that the repetitive replace do not replace any value twice. Please note that I have use the conversion of dfd to jimmy after jimmy is already converted to kanan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` like the following :

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET value = REPLACE(value, 'Jimmy', 'Kannan')
```

This will replace the 'Jimmy' strings with 'Kannan'. And then

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET value = REPLACE(value, 'dfd', 'Jimmy')
```

This will replace the 'dfd' strings with 'Jimmy'.

You could also combine these two (like Popeye's answer) :

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET value = REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'jimmy','kanan'),'dfd','jimmy')
```

Note that the order of the replace is important in this casee

Comment: there are so many record like this , can i do onetime without write again and again

Comment: You'll have to keep repeating the replace statements foe each case i.e. yeah you'll have to write REPLACE again and again. The other option  you have is to write a loop statement. Then, one single REPLACE should suffice.